# Any way to patch React Native 0.71.12?

Tags: react-native, build, patch

Is there any way to patch React Native 0.71.12?
I confirmed with RN maintainers, they don't have any proper documentation for building from source for this version.

I tried to build from source and publishing own version but both are not working on this version. and we cannot update to latest version for now.